# How to set Firestore security rules for create operation

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working on developing a mobile app in Flutter and using Firebase as backend.

Users will need to sign up to be able to use my app and I will save some user data in a `user_profile` collection in Firestore.
Since a new document will be added to the `user_profile` collection, I wonder how security rules should be set for creating a new document for the first time when the user registers.

Here is what happens during the sign up in my case:

```
// Step 1:  Register user with email and password
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

// Step 2: save user data in user_profile collection
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('user_profile')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set({
          'uid': user.uid,
          'email': email,
          'name': name,
          'date': DateTime.now,
        })
```

Since I save the user data in the `user_profile` collection after the call for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(..)` function is completed (meaning that the user is now authenticated), is it safe to define the security rule for create operation in Firebase as following? Or should I set it differently to make it secure in the right way?

```
// Rules for User Profile data
match /user_profile/{any} { 
  // Applies to writes to non-existent documents
  allow create: if request.auth != null; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, this should be fine but you could additionally check that the uid contained in the document corresponds to the authenticated user.

```
allow create: if request.auth != null && 
    request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
```